# CSS not rendering in FastAPI Jinja2Template

Tags: html, css, python-3.x, jinja2, fastapi

**UPDATE:** This solved.  I didn't write the correct CSS!

---

I am trying to render a few things in HTML.  Multiple things are causing problems but I've included the most basic part I want to get working.  If I can get this to work, I can get the rest to work.

Very simple app structure:

```
app
  api.py
  static
    styles.css
  templates
    index.html
```

This is the contents of `index.html`:

```
<html>
    <h1>
        Title here
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/styles.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </h1>
</html>
```

This the the CSS I'm using:

```
h1 {
    color: red
    text-align: center
}
```

Relevant code in `api.py`:

```
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")

@app.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def read_mean_cpu(request: Request, device_id):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request}))
```

Any idea why the CSS isn't taking?

Comment: How are you running the application? What is the entry point file? `api.py`?

Comment: @AndreFeijo Yeah `uvicorn api:app` so `api.py` is the entrypoint.

Comment: Could you please try this adding `./` to your static files directory? `StaticFiles(directory="./static")`

Comment: Done -- no change.

Comment: In the browser, when you run the page, are you seeing any errors in the console or network tab? What is the URL the browser is looking for the CSS file?

Comment: No errors but I realized I didn't semicolons in my CSS file :/

Comment: It happens to the best of us.

Comment: @AndreFeijo if only I would've had a syntax error!